# Renaming HTML files using the first of many <h2> tags, if forward slash is contained then replace this with hyphen

Tags: linux, bash, file-rename

I have a folder with a bunch of html files:

- SMG6E30A14100000000DAAT00.html
- SMB6E30A14400000000DAAT00.html
- SMA6E30A14400120000DAAT00.html
- etc...

I would like to rename each file according to the first `h2` tag in each file and if the tag contains a forward slash then the slash should be replaced with a hyphen.

So if SMG6E30A14100000000DAAT00.html contains

```html
</head><body><h2>Side Impact/Sensor (Second) Replacement</h2><a name="iR01"></a><h2><b>Removal</b></h2>
```

I would like the script to rename the file as Impact-Sensor (Second) Replacement.html

and if (there is no slash between first h2 tag)

```html
<h2>Front Seat Belt Replacement</h2>SRS components are located in this area. <a href="./SMG6E00H46400000000DAAT00.html">Review the SRS component locations</a> and the <a href="./SMG6E00H46400000000AAAT00.html">precautions and procedures</a> in the SRS before doing repairs or service.<br><br>NOTE: Check the front seat belts for damage, and replace them if necessary. Be careful not to damage them during removal and installation.<br><br><a name="iR01"></a><h2><b>Front Seat Belt</b></h2>
```

rename accordingly as Front Seat Belt Replacement.html

How do I do this on linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command returns the desired file name for `test.html`.

```
< ./test.html tr -d '\n' | grep -oP -m 1 '(?<=<h2>).*?(?=</h2>)' | head -1 | tr '/' '-'
```

You can create a shell script which uses this in a loop to scan all files, get the new filenames and rename them.

```
for filename in ./input/*.html; do

    newname=$(< ${filename} tr -d '\n' | grep -oP -m 1 '(?<=<h2>).*?(?=</h2>)' | head -1 | tr '/' '-')
    mv ${filename} "./output/${newname}.html"

done
```

Comment: It is working but there is a "bug",  if a filename.html doesn't contain a h2 tag then it gets deleted. It could leave as is these filenames.

Comment: Well, based on your specification I assumed that all of the files contain the necessary tag. However, if it is not true in all cases you can check the length of the newname variable and do the renaming only if the newname is not empty.